# Three different numbers with x³=x mod p

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

p is a prime greater than 2 and $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Why are there exactly three solutions for a³ = a mod p?
Obviously 0 and 1 are both in $\mathbb{Z}$ and valid solutions, but that still means, there is one element (and only one) missing. I can't figure out which one and neither do I understand why there could not be more valid solutions. Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless otherwise stated, $a$ is any integer representative of an eponymous element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
$$\begin{align}
a^3\equiv a\pmod p
&\Longleftrightarrow a^3-a\equiv0\pmod p\\
&\Longleftrightarrow a\cdot(a^2-1)\equiv0\pmod p\\
&\Longleftrightarrow a\cdot(a-1)\cdot(a+1)\equiv0\pmod p\\
&\Longleftrightarrow\begin{cases}
a\equiv0\pmod p&\text{ or}\\
a-1\equiv0\pmod p&\text{ or}\\
a+1\equiv0\pmod p
\end{cases}\end{align}$$
The last step uses that since $p$ is prime, if it divides the product of some integers [here: $a$, $a-1$, and $a+1$ ], then it must divide at least one of these integers. The reverse trivially holds without the hypothesis that $p$ is prime.

Since $p$ is greater than $2$, the three solutions $a\equiv0\pmod p$, $a\equiv1\pmod p$, $a\equiv p-1\pmod p$ are distinct elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Without the hypothesis that $p$ is prime, there can be additional solutions to $a^3\equiv a\pmod p$; for example, $a^3\equiv a\pmod{15}$ holds for nine out of fiteen elements $a$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$.

Keep in mind that $x\equiv0\pmod p$ means exactly the same as: $p$ divides $x$.

<sub>Thanks to CGFoX for having corrected the $a\cdot(a^2-1)$ expression.</sub>

Comment: One more thing: Not every third degree polynomial has three solutions in groups or finite fields. For example, $a^3-1 = 0$ has only then three solutions, if $\phi(p)$ is a multiple of $3$, because otherwise the function $f(x)=x^3$ mod $p$ is a bijection and $1$ has only one root. In the given equation it doesn't depend on $p$, because the solution $a=0$ is a given and $1$ has always two square roots (and $\phi(p)$ is always a multiple of $2$)

Answer (score 1):

The missing solution is $p-1$. This is a polynomial of degree 3, so (assuming $p$ is prime) it can have at most 3 roots. This polynomial in particular has exactly 3 roots (again, assuming $p$ is prime): you can factorize it to $a(a^2-1)=0 \pmod p$, so the roots are $a=0$ and the two roots of $a^2-1$, which are 1 and $-1 \bmod p=p-1$.

Comment: This shows there are _at least_ three solutions, not _exactly_ three solutions. In an arbitrary [ring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ring.html), it does _not_ hold that any polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots. You need to invoke the hypothesis on $p$ somehow.

Comment: The above comment was for [rev1](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/16572/1). $\;$ Call me picky but "_This_" in the second sentence can only refer to $p−1$, which is not a polynomial of degree 3 [ $a^3-a$ is the polynomial "_This_" is intended to designate]. $\;$The improved [rev2](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/16572/2) still does not tell how "$p$ _is prime_" implies that a polynomial of degree 3 has _at most_ 3 roots;$\;$ nor why there are _exactly_ 3 roots, which BTW does not hold for quite all primes $p$ as stated [we need to invoke "_greater than 2_" in the statement].